# Retain HTML tags in output from HTML file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to extract text and tags from a HTML webpage into a text file.

Here is the input webpage content (when viewed in view:source mode):

```
<div class="moduleBody">In addition, <b>ABC provides</b> dual finishing and detailing <u>products</u>, including a system of cleaners, dressings, polishes, waxes and other products.</p><p></p><p>Safety and Graphics Business</p><p></p><p>The Safety and Graphics segment serves a range of markets for the safety, security and productivity of people, facilities and systems. Its <b>product offerings</b> include personal protection products, such as <u>respiratory, hearing, eye and fall protection</u> equipment;<div class="moreLink">
```

The following code is working fine for extracting the text alone, but it is taking off the `<p>`, `</p>`, `<u>`, `</u>`, `<b>` and `</b>` as well as other HTML tags, which I want to preserve.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

use threads;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

my $Lvalue = "";

$mech->get($link);
$mech->quiet(1);

my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new(\$mech->content);

while ( my $tag1 = $p->get_tag('div') ) {

    if ( $tag1->[1]{class} and $tag1->[1]{class} eq 'moduleBody' ) {

        $Lvalue = $p->get_trimmed_text("moreLink");
        $Lvalue =~ s/$find1/|/g;
        $Lvalue =~ s/$find2/|/g;

        print $fh "$ticker^|$Lvalue\n";
    }
}
```

The output from the above code is:

```
In addition, ABC provides dual finishing and detailing products, including a system of cleaners, dressings, polishes, waxes and other products. Safety and Graphics Business The Safety and Graphics segment serves a range of markets for the safety, security and productivity of people, facilities and systems. Its product offerings include personal protection products, such as respiratory, hearing, eye and fall protection equipment;
```

Effectively, my code is removing the HTML tags which I want to retain.
I feel that "get_trimmed_text" may need to be tweaked to retain the p,/p,b and /b (and other html) tags.
Can someone help with any required changes to the code please?

**To clearly state the requirements:**
I'm looking for a perl function, which can help extract the (TEXT+ ALL HTML TAGS) that lie between "`<div class="moduleBody">`" and "`<div class="moreLink">`" on a webpage (as quoted in example input text above). I'm open to using other functions apart from get_trimmed_text.

Thanks a lot.

**ANSWER To THIS QUERY - for general audience**
The response provided by @SinanÜnür works well. Thanks @SinanÜnür! +1 and marking it as an answer. 
For the benefit of general audience, please note that Sinan Ünür's code works well as long as you keep the HTML content in the "`my $html = <<HTML;`" variable. The code needs a bit of tweaking to include the following if you are reading a URL:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $url = "http://www.example.com/profile?item=66&class=XYZ";
my $html = get($url);
```

Comment: Well, I provided a self-contained example. It is up to you to adapt that to how you obtain the source HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer updated following updates to the question.

> I'm looking for a perl function, which can help extract the (TEXT+ ALL HTML TAGS) that lie between "`<div class="moduleBody">`" and "`<div class="moreLink">`" on a webpage (as quoted in example input text above).

`HTML::TokeParser` is a stream parser: You ask for tokens or tags (which are specific kinds of tokens. So, using this module, you would ask the parser to find the next `div`, check if it is the right class, if so, start accumulating the content of all subsequent tokens up to the `<div class="moreLink">` opening tag.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $html = <<HTML;
<div class="moduleBody">In addition, <b>ABC provides</b>
dual finishing and detailing <u>products</u>, including a system of cleaners,
dressings, polishes, waxes and other products.</p><p></p><p>Safety and Graphics
Business</p><p></p><p>The Safety and Graphics segment serves a range of markets
for the safety, security and productivity of people, facilities and systems.
Its <b>product offerings</b> include personal protection products, such as
<u>respiratory, hearing, eye and fall protection</u> equipment;<div
class="moreLink">
HTML

my $p = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(\$html);
my $start = { tag => 'div', class => 'moduleBody' };
my $end = { tag => 'div', class => 'moreLink' };

while ( defined(my $chunk = extract_html_between($p, $start, $end)) ) {
    print "[[[$chunk]]]\n"
}

sub extract_html_between {
    my $p = shift;
    my $start = shift;
    my $end = shift;

    my $chunk;
    while (my $tag = $p->get_tag($start->{tag})) {
        my $class = $tag->get_attr('class');
        next unless $class and $class eq $start->{class};

        $chunk = $tag->as_is; # only if you want the opening div
        CHUNK:
        while (my $token = $p->get_token) {
            if ( $token->is_start_tag($end->{tag}) ) {
                $class = $token->get_attr('class');
                last CHUNK if $class and $class eq $end->{class};
            }
            $chunk .= $token->as_is;
        }
    }

    return $chunk;
}
```

Output:

```
[[[<div class="moduleBody">In addition, <b>ABC provides</b>
dual finishing and detailing <u>products</u>, including a system of cleaners,
dressings, polishes, waxes and other products.</p><p></p><p>Safety and Graphics
Business</p><p></p><p>The Safety and Graphics segment serves a range of markets
for the safety, security and productivity of people, facilities and systems.
Its <b>product offerings</b> include personal protection products, such as
<u>respiratory, hearing, eye and fall protection</u> equipment;]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's very strange code. You're not using `WWW::Mechanize` for anything more than fetching the web page, so you may as well use `LWP::UserAgent` directly. Also, `HTML::TokeParser` isn't the right tool if you want to extract parr of an HTML resource and print it

You don't even appear to have read the documentation, as `$p->get_trimmed_text("moreLink")` will return all text up until the first occurence of a `<moreLink>` element, which isn't a valid HTML tag. What you have there is the value of the `class` attribute of the `div` element you have just found

I would choose [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) for this, as it will fetch the page, build a DOM, and stringify the element you specify, without any additional modules

I've written this, but I'm not in a position to test it at present

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Mojo::UserAgent;

use constant URL => 'http://example.com/';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $txn = $ua->get(URL);

if ( my $err = $txn->error ) {
    die "@{$err}{qw/ code message /};
}

print $txn->res->dom->at('div.moduleBody')->to_string;
```

Comment: Given OP's HTML, that prints an extra **`<div class="moreLink">
</div></div>`** at the end. That is the benefit of using a stream parser instead of constructing a DOM. You can stop whereever you want no matter how broken the HTML is.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: I agree. Before the OP's update, everything seemed to point to them wanting just a verbatim version of the HTML shown. I'm still bemused by the two substitutions. Anyway, I'm leaving this here for the benefit of others coming here with a less arcane requirement.